# Disable "Would you like to make Microsoft edge your default browser?" (the new Edge)

Tags: microsoft-edge

Whenever I start the Chromium-based version of Microsoft Edge ("new Edge") on my computer, I see this nag:

[image]

No, I don't want to make Microsoft Edge my default browser. I wish it would stop asking me. I've tried setting the registry key

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\Main\DisallowDefaultBrowserPrompt`

as a 32-bit DWORD with a value of 1. It doesn't help.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the new Edge. Is that correct? You may want to state it prominently in your question.

Comment: For me this registry entry already existed and was already set to 1. I had to change it to 0 to disable the nag.

Comment: Still_dreaming solution worked for me too, that should be the accepted answer.